# DI: constructor of class how injectable calls serveral times

Tags: typescript, inversifyjs

There are several classes, how injected `TermsExchangeService`:

```
import {TermsExchangeService} from './terms-exchange.service';

@injectable()
export class TermsExchangeComponent {
  constructor(
        private termsExchangeService: TermsExchangeService
    ) {}
}
```

and

```
import {TermsExchangeService} from './terms-exchange.service';

@injectable()
export class PurchaseMainComponent {
    constructor(
       private termsExchangeService: TermsExchangeService
    ) {}
```

and service how has been used in `PurchaseMainComponent` and `TermsExchangeComponent`

```
@injectable()
export class TermsExchangeService {

    constructor() {
        debugger; // call 2 times!!!
    }
}
```

I use `autoBindInjectable`:

```
var simpleContainer = new Container({ autoBindInjectable: true })
```

When getting components from loop constructor of `TermsExchangeService` call several times:

```
for (let item = 0; item < components.length; item++) {
   const container = simpleContainer.get(components[item]);
}
```

Why object created in every components? And how do normal injections?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default `injectable` is not Singleton.

Solve this problem can adding `defaultScope: 'Singleton'`:

```
var simpleContainer = new Container(
            { 
               autoBindInjectable: true, 
               defaultScope: 'Singleton'
            }
)
```